# how to remove client certificate from iPhone application?

Tags: ios, security, client, certificate

I have an iPhone application which accesses a secure (https) web-service. The service requires  a client certificate to authenticate the client. I added the client certificate (.p12 format) to the application and implemented the NSURL delegate method to respond to authentication challenges (didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge). It works as expected.

Now when I delete the certificate from my application, it still works. Where does it find the client certificate? Is it cached somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Only way i managed to do it was to jailbreak iphone, install cydia, login by ssh and delete whole certificates chain file.

If user deleted profile containing certificate it is still in the file ! (maybe there is some flag marking it as inactive)